# What does っちゅう mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> 難しい言葉でなくても、道路の表札には、途中で切れずにとても長い道路の名前が書いてあることが諸**っちゅう**あります。

Obviously, I should describe the context behind this sentence, so here goes:

On Tell Me!goo (教えて!goo), there is a question where the questioner asks, “Please tell me about the differences between ‘今’ and ‘現在’”. You can read about it here: https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/4537310.html

One answer in particular is interesting. It says that ‘今’ and ‘現在’ have the same meaning, and that ‘今’ is a Japanese word of Japanese origin and ‘現在’ is a Japanese word of Chinese origin (i.e. a loanword). This implies that ‘今’ is used for casual conversations and ‘現在’ is used for formal writing. Then it cites Germany as an example of a country that avoids loanwords as much as it can, and that results in very long nouns.

Then it arrives at the sentence. When I use Google Translate, I get the following sentence as a result:

> Even if it is not a difficult language, there are many things in the nameplate on the road that the name of a very long road is written without being able to cut along the way.

Obviously, it is not a perfect translation, but it is a start.

When I looked up っちゅう on the following website (https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A1%E3%82%85%E3%81%86), it says that it is a conjunction and colloquialism that means “meaning; called; said”.

I wonder if that part of the sentence is trying to say, “...there are many said instances of....”

Am I on the right track here?

Comment: Prolly 当て字(?) for しょっちゅう. Only 75 Google search results, so doesn't appear to be too common.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ×「**諸{しょ}っちゅう**あります」

is typo of...

> 〇「**しょっちゅう**あります」

, which in this context means that something happens **often** or **all the time**.

Comment: It was a spelling mistake?! So that's why I couldn't find much of anything! Typos in Japanese sentences make them challenging to translate. Then again, Japanese probably get headaches translating English sentences that have typos in them, am I right?

Comment: Something makes me think that adding kanji into the mix makes the Japanese variety just a tad more insidious ;P - But English grammar typos... ooooh that's got to be a tough one

Comment: @MichealGignac It's an inevitable aspect of kana-kanji conversion. A single slip of the finger could blow a word miles away. If you know enough of oral Japanese, it's easy to guess from intended pronunciation, but if you don't...